# Ошибка в генерации чисел на Basic

Tags: случайные-числа, basic

У меня Андроид 6. Я установил приложение Frodo C64 (это эмулятор компьютера Commodore 64 со встроенным компилятором Basic)
Я написал код:

```
10 A=INT (RND(1)*2)
20 IF A="1" THEN PRINT "YOU WON"
30 IF A="2" THEN PRINT "YOU LOSE"
```

Далее я написал:"RUN", но компилятор пишет:
"?TYPE MISMATCH ERROR IN 20".
Как я понимаю, это ошибка в строке 20. Но что делать?

Comment: `IF A="1"` ... у вас `A` это число, а вы его со строкой `"1"` сравниваете?

Comment: Переменная A генерирует два числа. Если "1", то одна надпись. Если " 2", то другая.

Comment: Вам говорят о разнице типов - целое число и строка. В кавычках - строка

Comment: `IF A=1` попробуйте написать

Comment: На языке Python и Java компилятор понимает что "если A сгенерировало один, то будет что-то (команда print), а если A сгенерировало два, то можно и другое слово вывести....

Answer (score 0):

Вот верный код:

```
10 A=INT(RND(1)*2)
20 IF A=0 THEN PRINT "ZERO"
30 IF A=1 THEN PRINT "ONE"
```